# What is the full procedure after editing SSIS package in a Visual Studio project?

Tags: sql, ssis, checkin

I have a Winforms project that includes SSIS packages. Recently, due to a Windows checking that broke provider Jet, resulting in Excel imports failing, I applied the fix, which is to use Ace instead of Jet. Now, the SSIS package runs and passes again.

That's the only change I made. No code changes to the Winforms application.

Anyway, I checked in my change.

We use Team Foundation Server, Click Once application deployment, and also run nightly jobs using SQL Server Agent which uses the SSIS packages and runs specific sequences within the SSIS package. I think there are 5 sequences and there's a separate job for each in SQL Server Agent.

I'm still relatively new and was wondering what is the right process to make sure all my i's are dotted and t's are crossed and the only change I made is to an SSIS package in a Visual Studio project and then I check it in.

Like, do I need to also publish? I didn't think I would need to since it's only an SSIS package change, and doesn't impact the application side. So users would not need another click once update. Is that right, or do I still need to publish?

Also, I need to somehow get my SSIS package changes to be seen on the SQL Server Agent jobs. Am I supposed to copy over the updated .dtsx file to some location on the SQL Server Agent?

We don't appear to have a SSIS catalog or database used that registers the SSIS packages, since when I clicked on those folders, they were empty.

SQL Agent Job shows Package source as "SQL Server".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are they running as file system packages in SQL Agent ?

Comment: I believe so, but how do I confirm?  I know we have scheduled jobs in SQL Server Agent but I don't think they are in a catalog or database because when I clicked on such folders, there was no content.